# Is it possible to get currently active keyboard view in android

Tags: android, keyboard

I want add KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener in my activity so i need the object of currently active keyboard view

Answer (score 0):

No.  First off, the Keyboard is in another process.  You can't get the object.  Second-  almost no keyboards actually use KeyboardView.  It's too restrictive.  They almost all make their own custom views.